# .NET-Core Web API routing to diffrent process

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core

My goal is to implement a generically extendible .NET core web API. The generic refers to modules that can be added at runtime and provide new endpoints as well as functionality. These modules will be developed based on a framework.

Currently I am still deciding if the modules will be included as a DLL or run as a separate process (.exe).
I have the basic understanding of Dependenci Injection regarding the addressing of controllers in a DLL. But now I wonder if and how to realize the whole thing via an own process.

The API should always be addressable via http://localhost/myapi/{endpoint}, i.e. a request to a module should be done via the same URL. For the user / developer of the frontend everything should be presented as one API.

Unfortunately I was not successful on my research and don't know exactly what I have to / should look for specifically. Therefore I hope that you can help me.
Examples are helpful, but I am also keywords or articles, which deal with such a topic, help me further.

kind regards

Comment: This is really too broad for a question. Try to narrow it down: like I've set up project X and I want to call process Y and I tried this and that, and it didn't work. Or: I'm looking for ways to call another process, I tried to do it like this, and I'm not sure it's the right way.

Comment: You can have a look at [Razor Class Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class) that allow you to define new endpoints in a separate assembly.